# How to make service TCP/UDP ports externally accessible in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I have many tenants running on one Kubernetes cluster (on AWS), where every tenant has one Pod that exposes one **TCP** port (**not HTTP**) and one **UDP** port.

- I don't need load balancing capabilities.
- The approach should expose an IP address that is externally available with a dedicated port for each tenant
- I don't want to expose the nodes directly to the internet

I have the following service so far:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
  labels:
    app: my-app
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 8111
      targetPort: 8111
      protocol: UDP
      name: my-udp
    - port: 8222
      targetPort: 8222
      protocol: TCP
      name: my-tcp
  selector:
    app: my-app
```

What is the way to go?

Comment: You need to use kubernetes services. Here's a detailed answer I wrote for a similar question that might be useful to you - https://stackoverflow.com/a/50080291/1220089.

I'm not the one who downvoted, but I suspect your question is a duplicate.

Comment: You can use Ingress (it is supported on GKE but I don't know about AWS) and attach that to reverse proxy.

Answer (score 3):

- [Deploy](https://medium.com/kokster/how-to-setup-nginx-ingress-controller-on-aws-clusters-7bd244278509) a NGINX ingress controller on your AWS cluster
- Change your service my-service type from `NodePort` to `ClusterIP`
- Edit the configMap `tcp-services` in the `ingress-nginx` namespace adding :

> ```
> data:
>   "8222": your-namespace/my-service:8222
> ```

- Same for configMap `udp-services` :

> ```
> data:
>   "8111": your-namespace/my-service:8111
> ```

Now, you can access your application externally using the nginx-controller IP `<ip:8222>` (TCP) and `<ip:8111>` (UDP)

Comment: mention in this https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/ don't forget to modify the service of ingress

Answer (score -1):

The [description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46307289/routing-traffic-to-kubernetes-cluster/50080291#50080291) provided by @ffledgling is what you need.

But I have to mention that if you want to expose ports, you have to use a load balancer or expose nodes to the Internet. For example, you can expose a node to the Internet and allow access only to some necessary ports.

Comment: AWS Load Balancer does not support UDP, only TCP. Also, I don't want to create an AWS Load Balancer for every tenant => Expensive. If I only expose one node, then this node does become a single point of failure.

Comment: @mitchkman Actually, you don't have any other choice except exposing node(s) for UDP and TCP or use separate AWS ELB for TCP. Also, you can expose more than 1 node. There are no magic here. "I don't want to expose the nodes directly to the internet" - it is not possible on AWS for UDP at all and for TCP without ELB.